# Only one call from concurrent request with 60 sec timeout

Tags: php, time, io

I have a function  `callUpdate()` that needs to be executed after every update in the webpage admin.

callUpdates execute some caching (and takes up to 30 sec..) so it is not important to execute it immediately but in reasonable amount of time after the last update lets say 60 sec.

The goal is to skip processing if the user (users) make several consecutive changes in a short amount of time.

here is my current code:

```
//this in separate stand alone script that is called asynchronous way
//so hanging for 1min does not and block the app.

function afterUpdate(){
    $time = time(); 
    file_put_contents('timer.txt', $time); 

    sleep(60);

    if (file_get_contents("timer.txt") == $time) {
        callUpdate();
    } 
}
```

My concerns here are bout the sleep function .. if it takes too much resources 
(if I make 10 quick saves, this will start 10 PHP processes running for almost 60 sec each ..)

And what will happen if 2 users call simultaneously `file_put_contents()` on the same file.

Please tell me if there is better approach and if there are some major issues in mine.

NOTE: data between sessions can be stored only in a file
and there I have limited access to the server setup "APC settings and such"

Comment: Sleep is not a good idea, it will block a php process. I better idea would be to let the user decide when to update the cache, with a big [rebuild cache] button.

Comment: Regarding your `file_put_contents` concurrency access question : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171508/php-file-put-contents-file-locking

Comment: @user574632 true, but I don't trust the user. What if he never caches .. or caches every time?